# What is wrong with this graphql schema? Type mismatch for Index Key

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, amplifyjs

When i use the new DataStore plugin from aws:

```
await DataStore.save(
          new User({
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe"
          })
        )
```

The request to the graphql api in appsync contains: userStatusId: null. That leads to the error: "Type mismatch for Index Key". I don´t want that field at the time of creating a user. So how do i get rid of it? A user can have one status. A status can be in many users. When i query with `DataStore.query(User)` I´d like to have all the relational fields like status in it. This parts works when using the schema below.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  firstname: String
  lastname: String!
  status: Status @connection(name: "StatusUsers")
}

type Status @model {
  id: ID!
  users: [User] @connection(name: "StatusUsers")
  name: String
}
```

If i do the relationship the other way around the save part works, but i don´t get the relational Status data when querying the users.

thanks

Comment: How many Status do you have? for example online and offline? or more

Comment: The user can dynamically choose from a list of status they created. There are also many more relations like status. For example: location, tag, project, ...

Comment: You can leave it black at the time of creating a user but later you should update it, otherwise, as you said, you can't get query users with relational Status data.so just ignore `userStatusId` in `DataStore.save` result.

Comment: That´s the problem. You can´t leave it blanck. Cause of the error: "Type mismatch for Index Key"

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue but with your schema everything went well. if your schema is different, please update the question. Personally, I think `Type mismatch for Index Key` comes from Dynamodb.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It seems it has something to do with the new api. Though ios is not the thing i use. But it might be the same: [link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3109).